# Creating Multiple tuples based of of user input

Tags: java, mysql

I just have a question about MySql + java. I need to be able to create tuples based off of user input.

So the question will come up

"How many tuples would you like in Department Table?"
User: 100.

100 Tuples created in Department Table.

I know a loop will be used but I am just not sure to go about.

Not looking for people to do my HWk, but just a beginner looking for a little direction.

Thanks in advance.

Brandon

Edit:

// I had to do a increment for the Pk;

Actually I got it. Just used a

```
'While (count < userinput)
{
       insert into department (col1,col2,col3) values ('"+counts+"', null, null)



       counts++;
       count++;


}
```

'

Comment: So you want a table with a bunch of empty tuples?

Comment: Yes just a table bunch of null values.

Comment: If youre actually interested in learning to program: consider learning about schema because it has a wide variety of uses like dynamically gererating forms and tables for a user.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make a table that stores department id size and name, then have a table for the user input with a corresponding department id for each tuple.

### Department

```
did int primary key
size int
name varchar(100)
```

### Content

```
id int autoincrement
did int
content1 int
content2 int
```

Department stores listings of departments,
Content stores listings of user input for ALL departments.